# Last() function in XPATH works correctly in Chrome browser, but it doesn't work in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I use this XPATH `//div[@class="col-md-12"]/*[self::p or self::ul][position()<=last()-1]` to a site (I can't disclose the website's name due to my job. Sorry) in Chrome browser, and it works just okay, but then it returns `None` in Scrapy.

When I change the XPATH to `//div[@class="col-md-12"]/*[self::p or self::ul][position()<=3]`, it works okay. How can I use before last function in Scrapy?

Comment: What is it you wanna parse from there? Is it the content of `p` tag only? The last `p` tag has got something to display but the second last `p` tag contains none but whitespaces. However, did you try like this `//div[@class='col-md-12']/*[self::p][last()]`?

Comment: Share HTML sample for the `//div[@class="col-md-12"]` and element you want to select